# Python: flag if column value in each row contains a specific word

Tags: python, loops, pandas, for-loop

I have a data frame that contains a column called 'body' in which each cell is full of text strings (i.e. comments from a message board).

I am trying to write code that goes through each row and says if the word 'IT' (needs to be uppercase only) is in the cell, then create a new column and label the row 'IT_flag".  Else label it 'None'.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't appear to work:

```
test = v3['body']

for i in test:
    if 'IT' in i:
        test['IT_Flag'] = "IT_Flag"
    else:
        test['IT_Flag'] = "None"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Because to me, what you explain is exactly what the code also does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = {"A": ['IT is here', "it ain't here", 'this is it', "IT headquarters"]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)

    print(df)
#                     A
#    0       IT is here
#    1    it ain't here
#    2       this is it
#    3  IT headquarters


    def check_it(input_str):
        if "IT" in input_str:
            return True
        return False

    df.loc[:, 'flag'] = df.A.apply(check_it)

    print(df)
 #                    A   flag
 #   0       IT is here   True
 #   1    it ain't here  False
 #   2       this is it  False
 #   3  IT headquarters   True
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use `str.contains` and `np.where` to convert the boolean array to string:

```
In [123]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'body':['asdad kkn', 'IT1', 'IT', 'It', 'XIT']})
df

Out[123]:
        body
0  asdad kkn
1        IT1
2         IT
3         It
4        XIT

In [125]:
df['IT_flag'] = np.where(df['body'].str.contains('^IT$'), 'IT_flag', 'None')
df

Out[125]:
        body  IT_flag
0  asdad kkn     None
1        IT1     None
2         IT  IT_flag
3         It     None
4        XIT     None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'body':['asdad kkn', 'IT1', 'IT', 'It', 'XIT']})

In [6]: df['IT_flag'] = df['body']=='IT' 

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
        body IT_flag
0  asdad kkn   False
1        IT1   False
2         IT    True
3         It   False
4        XIT   False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the content of the thing you're iterating through. Instead, try (assuming `test` is a list):

```
for i in list(test):
    **do stuff**
```

This will create a copy of the list, and will to modify the value in `test`.

But be aware that by modifying the object in every iteration, you'll only end up with the result in the last cell.